# How to convert vector<pair<string, T>> to vector<pair<string,string>>

Tags: c++, vector, graph

I have a method that requires me to return a vector<pair<string, string>>. However, the input I have is of vector `<pair<string, T>>`. This is part of a bigger question to return the number of edges in a graph. The relevant code is down below where `T` is an integer type.

```
map<string, string> all_vertices;
map<string, map<string, T>> adj_list;

template<typename T>
size_t Graph<T>::num_edges() {
    int edge_num = 0;

    for(auto& node : adj_list) {
        for(auto& edge : node.second) {
            edge_num++;
        }
    }

    return edge_num / 2;
}

template<typename T>
void Graph<T>::add_edge(const string& u, const string& v, const T& weight) {
    if(!adjacent(u, v)) {
        if(adj_list[u].find(v) == adj_list[u].end()) {
            adj_list[u].insert({v, weight});
            adj_list[v].insert({u, weight});
        }
    }
}

template <typename T>
void Graph<T>::add_vertex(const string& u) {
    
        if(!contains(u)){
            all_vertices.insert({u,u}); 
            adj_list[u]= map<string, T>();
     }
    
}

template <typename T>
bool Graph<T>::adjacent(const string& u, const string& v) {

     if(contains(u) && contains(v)){
        if (adj_list[u].find(v)!=adj_list[u].end()){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
    
}

template<typename T>
vector<pair<string, string>> Graph<T>::get_edges() {
    vector<pair<string, T>> e;
    vector<pair<string, string>> e_string;
    for(auto x1 : adj_list) {
        for(auto x2 : x1.second) {
            e.push_back(x2);
        }
    }

    return e;
}
/* the test cases for the nodes in the graphs:

Number of vertices: 5

Number of edges: 8

Is vertex A in the graph? 1

Is vertex F in the graph? 0

Is there an edge between A and B? 1

Is there an edge between B and C? 0

*/
```

Description for the different functions:

- `vector<pair<string,string>> get_edges();`
  returns a vector of all the edges in the graph -- each edge is represented by a pair of vertices incident to the edge.
- `void add_edge(const string&, const string&, const T&);`
  adds a weighted edge to the graph -- the two strings represent the incident vertices; the third parameter represents the edge's weight.

Comment: T allows the weight of an edge to take any numeric data type

Comment: so what you expected to get? `to_string` result?

Comment: Please explain what your input *means* and what you want your output to *mean*.

Comment: I'm basically trying to loop around the map containing the edges and then putting the elements into the vector. however since the return value vector has to be of type <string, string> and the map is of type <string, T>, I'm not sure how to convert it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo T is an integer

Comment: Declare `e` as: `vector<pair<string, string>> e;` and invoke the `push_back` call as `e.push_back(std::to_string(x2));`

Comment: @TedLyngmo I made return e to hold all the the edges of type <string, T>. While e_string was to then convert it into type <string, string> . Probably a poor logic.

Comment: @SamuelWibawa What is the purpose of `get_edges` really? It will contain one vertex and the weight (converted to `string`). What can that be used for? Are you sure it shouldn't contain a pair of vertices (without the weight)?

Comment: It is just part of the requirements of what the question asks. It needs to return a vector of all the edges in the graph. Each edge is represented by a pair of vertices incident to the edge.

Comment: @SamuelWibawa Ok, but your `get_edges` (and mine too) only put _one_ vertex per edge + the weight in the result. Once vertex + a weight doesn't make an edge. Shouldn't it be the two vertices (without the weight) that is put in the result from this function?

Comment: I understand what you're trying to say. I just don't know how to implement the changes myself on the code.

Comment: @SamuelWibawa I've added an alternative solution to my answer - If you could add the exact requirements on the `get_edges` function to the question it'd be great too.

Comment: Yes please do. It would help greatly. There is no other requirement for the get_edges function. I can however, give you the descriptions of each function as stated by my question. I'll  update it above.

Comment: The `add_vertex` function seems to make it possible to add unconnected vertices that are then kept in a separate `map` - which maps them to themselves. What's the point of that? You could use a `set<std::string>` for unconnected vertices - or just add unconnected vertices to the same `adj_list` as the connected ones. Also, the vertices you now add via `add_edge` are _not_ stored in `all_vertices`, so, `all_vertices` will _not_ contain all vertices.

Comment: I understand now. You've helped me a lot. Thanks again sir. There are other questions I'm working on where I still struggle logically on what to do. If you would like to see where I'm going wrong or where my logic is flawed, would you mind if I post them as well. If not, then I totally understand.

Comment: @SamuelWibawa Great, glad it helped! Just post new questions and everyone at SO can help. Strive for asking one question per question so to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you skip the intermediate step of creating `e` and go directly to `e_string`. Also, make `get_edges()` `const` since you're not changing `*this`.

Use `std::to_string` to convert the integer `T` to a `std::string`.

The real problem is however that your code tries to add only one *vertex* + the weight for each edge.

In your description of the problem it says that it should be a pair of vertices. It doesn't say that the weight should be included.

So, here's how that can be done:

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> Graph<T>::get_edges() const {
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> e_string;
 
    for (auto&[u, Map] : adj_list) {
         // only add one direction, get all v's where u < v:
        for(auto vw_it = Map.upper_bound(u); vw_it != Map.end(); ++vw_it) {
            e_string.emplace_back(u, vw_it->first);
        }
    }
    
    return e_string;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9P8E1Tb5j)

---

Unrelated suggestions:

You could simplify the `num_edges()` method (which should also be `const`). You now loop over all the elements in the inner `map` to count them, but the `map` has a `size()` member function, so that is not necessary:

```
#include <numeric>  // std::accumulate

template<typename T>
size_t Graph<T>::num_edges() const {
    return
        std::accumulate(adj_list.begin(), adj_list.end(), size_t{0},
            [](size_t sum, const auto& node) {
                return sum + node.second.size();
            }) / 2;
}
```

In `add_edge` you could skip checking if the connection is already there and just try to add it. It'll be rejected if it's a duplicate:

```
template<typename T>
void Graph<T>::add_edge(const std::string& u, const std::string& v,
                        const T& weight)
{
    if(u == v) return; // don't allow linking a vertex with itself
    adj_list[u].emplace(v, weight);
    adj_list[v].emplace(u, weight);
}
```

You may still want to have the `adjacent` function. In that case I'd simplify it to something like this:

```
template <typename T>
bool Graph<T>::adjacent(const string& u, const string& v) const {
    auto it = adj_list.find(u);
    return it != adj_list.end() && it->second.find(v) != it->second.end();

    // return it != adj_list.end() && it->second.contains(v); // C++20
}
```

Comment: This works! I'm not sure what you did here, but I'm keen to find out.  Why did you use auto&[str, Int]?.  Thanks for the response by the way :)

Comment: Yeah there is just one more thing I'm not sure about. Apparently the correct number of edges is (the I got answer / 2). How do I divide the numbers inside the map by 2 before I add it into the vector?

Comment: @TedLyngo that still doesn't divide the return value by 2.

Comment: I've updated the main question accordingly with the other functions that relate to the number of edges I have to return. I hope it gives better information

Comment: Yes that's right. Its an undirected graph so it wouldn't matter which edge is selected

Comment: That seemed to compile fine and I'm sure it works. I just have another error from another function that seems affected by the code. I'll see if I can fix it. Thanks again

Comment: Sure. Thanks for that. Is there a way I can message you privately since this thread is getting longer?

Comment: Oh that's ok. If it doesn't come online soon, would you be comfortable talking via email?

Comment: No worries. The last error that seems to stop the code from compiling properly is from an error that says :  'Assertion failed: g.adjacent(vp.first, vp.second)'. I get that it's probably from the adjacent function I have, but I'm not sure what the problem is. I've posted the relevant code above in my original. It's just the adjacent function

Comment: @SamuelWibawa I don't see `g.adjacent(vp.first, vp.second)` in the code. Is that really a compilation error (a `static_assert`ion) or is it a runtime `assert`ion? Anyway, I don't see any reasons to do the `adjacent` test in `add_edge`. Just add the edge and it'll be rejected if it's a duplicate.

Comment: Apparently the error occurs because both vertices aren't adjacent, and thus if two vertices are not adjacent, they cannot form an edge, and you cannot return this pair as an edge in your get_edges() function.

Comment: @SamuelWibawa Did you try the alternate solution? I removed the old one now and put my suggestion in a demo (linked in the answer).

Comment: Yes that worked! Thank you for helping me out. Can you explain what you did by placing comments in the demo code? I'm intrigued as to why this worked and why it didn't.

Comment: @SamuelWibawa Ok, I will add more comments in a few hours. Can you perhaps add comments in the demo where you would like to get a better explanation and paste that link here? It'll help me to concentrate on the right thing.

Comment: Sure. I basically thought that the code wasn't being marked properly because there was only one edge being added in (since there is no edge connecting B and C, whereas there is an edge connecting A and B. The letters represent the nodes that are being added in as part of the test cases- I've put the test case output  as a comment in the original post). I've also added in the function that adds the vertices in, just in case my logic there is also flawed.

Comment: @SamuelWibawa "_there was only one edge being added_" - In the demo there are 6 edges. `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are all connected to all the other vertices. `b` and `c` are among them, so I don't quite understand what you mean. Did you add the function that is adding the vertices? I don't see it in your question. Did you try to run the tests with the `get_edges` function I made? Did it work? Do you understand what it's doing or is it there I should try to explain things better?

Comment: Yes, I ran the tests with the get_edges function that you made and it worked. I'm just not sure why it didn't work last time as it kept coming up with the 'adjacency' error. I've also added in the function 'Add Vertex' that explains how I added in all the vertices.

Comment: "_it worked_" - Great! "_not sure why it didn't work last time_" - I would have to see the `get_edges` function you used that time to be able to help with that - but don't put that in the question - it will mess up the question. You can share it via https://godbolt.org/ or https://pastebin.com/ if you want me to take a look at that.

Do you understand how the `get_edges` function in this answer works? If you don't fully understand it, I will add more details in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, without modifying your code too much, would be to convert T to string at input.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using std::vector;
using std::string;
using std::map;
using std::pair;

map<string, string> all_vertices;

template <typename T>
map<string, map<string, T>> adj_list;

template <typename T>
vector<pair<string, string>> Graph<T>::get_edges() const {

   vector<pair<string, T>> e;

   for (auto x1 : adj_list<T>) {
      for (auto x2 : x1.second) {
         e.push_back(x2);

      }
   }

   return e;
}

// Graph<string> g;
// vector<pair<string, string>> edges = g.get_edges();
```